# How do I add Angular functionality to newly-added HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an HTML page with Angular. I want to click a button that adds an Angular `input` tag to the DOM. But when I do so, the new `input` text field does not seem to work the way I would expect it.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app=    angular.module("myApp",[]);
        app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){

        });

        $(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(){
                $("body").append("<input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"bar\"><br>{{bar}}");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="button">click me</button>
  <input type="text" name="something" ng-model="foo"><br>
  {{foo}}
</body>
</html>
```

I can use Angular's functions just fine when with the `input` tag already there. When I type something in the text field, the output appears. But when I click the button and the new `input` text field comes up, typing in it does nothing.

What am I missing?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix JQUERY and Angular in the way you are doing it. You have to choose one framework and stick to its principles.

In order to add a control the "View" in angular you could use "**Directives**". Another options is to have an object in your **Model** and the chances to this object will interact with your controller and this will inform the **View** to add another control.

Angular is an MVC framework therefore you should not manipulate the View(html) through another framework. Angular was meant to fix and simplify this manipulations with a proper separation or layers.

You can refer to this other post on how to perform this:

[How to dynamically add input rows to view and maintain value in angularjs ng-model as array item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23986536/1959948)

Answer (score 0):

To do it in AngularJS:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button id="button" ng-click="showBarInput=true">click me</button>
  <div ng-show="showBarInput">
      <input type="text" ng-model="bar"><br>
      {{bar}}
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="something" ng-model="foo"><br>
  {{foo}}
</body>
```

The AngularJS framework is a Model-View-Whatever framework. The model drives the view. In this case, `$scope.showBarInput` controls the visibility of the elements.